# jQuery find two types of children elements

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have a checkbox which toggles elements under `<section>` and

I am trying to apply `readonly` to inputs and `readonly` to selects and buttons, how can I achieve that in on jQuery statement?

How can I make jQuery `find` twice with the same selector?

```
        $(this).parents('section')
            .eq(0)
            .find('input') <-- found all the inputs under <section>
            .not('.cloud-media-toggle-inputs')
            .prop('readonly', ! isChecked )
            .find('select, button') <-- now I want to find all the <select>/<button> under <section>
            .prop('disabled', ! isChecked );
```

Comment: How do you mean, "find twice"? It will already find all matching elements of the page, however many there are. Do you want to change what the selector is each time?

Comment: Put `end()` after the first `prop()` to return the selection to the `section` element

Comment: @samiles I've re-edited the title of the question, hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

```
    $(this).parents('section')
        .eq(0)
        .find('input')
        .not('.cloud-media-toggle-inputs')
        .prop('readonly', !isChecked )
        .end() //<===========
        .find('select, button') 
        .prop('disabled', !isChecked );
```

---

Or, Don't use chaining

```
var sectionFirstChild = $(this).parents('section').eq(0);
sectionFirstChild.find('input:not(.cloud-media-toggle-inputs)').prop('readonly', !isChecked);
sectionFirstChild.find('select, button').prop('disabled', !isChecked);
```

Comment: @Broshi, Can yo share the HTML?

Comment: not really, its a part of a backend page with lots of HTML...i'll tackle it again or just do a double jquery lookup